# How to create a webhook from curl or github cli

Tags: github, curl, github-api, github-cli

How do you create a webhook from curl or github cli?

This doc. does not help a lot:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook--code-samples

Tried this:

```sh
curl -u <user>:<token>\
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/hooks \
    -d '{"name":"name"}'
```

Leaves me with questions:

- What is `-d '{"name":"name"}'`
- How do you add a config

Errors:

```json
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
    {
        "resource": "Hook",
        "code": "custom",
        "message": "Config must contain URL for webhooks"
    }
    ],
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using curl

You can use the following to create a webhook:

```sh
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/hooks" \
     -H "Authorization: Token YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -d @- << EOF
{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "push"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "http://some_webhook.ngrok.io/webhook",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
EOF
```

From [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook), `name` property should have the value `web`

| Name | Type | In | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | string | body | Use web to create a webhook. Default: web. This parameter only accepts the value web. |

Possible webhook events are listed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads)

#### Using Github CLI

```sh
gh api /repos/<org>/<repo>/hooks \
   --input - <<< '{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "watch"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "https://some_webhook.ngrok.io/webhook",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}'
```

Checkout [gh api](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api)