# Create a Github Webhook using the github CLI

Tags: github, webhooks, enterprise

I work a company that uses Github Enterprise and I am trying to create a webhook to listen to our repo and update our workboard. While researching, I have only found ways to create a webhook using the Github UI in the browser and clicking on the "Settings" tab. Normally it is at the top of the repo by the other tabs except in this case, where this is what I see
[image: tabs at the top of repo]

Is there another way to create a webhook using the Github CLI?

Since I can't use the UI, I have tried the CLI with this curl command:
curl POST "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" "Authorization: Bearer " "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos///hooks '{"name":"web","active":true,"events":["merge","pull_request"],"config":{"url":"https://example.com/webhook","content_type":"json","insecure_ssl":"0"}}'

but I get back a 404 resource does not exist.

Comment: duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478970/how-to-create-a-webhook-from-curl-or-github-cli

Answer (score 1):

This took me a bit of experimenting but I figured it out.

```
echo '{"name":"web","active":true,"events":["push","pull_request","release"],"config":{"url":"WEBHOOK_URL","content_type":"form","insecure_ssl":"0"}}' | gh api repos/ORGANIZATION/REPO/hooks --input - -X POST
```

To break it up I'm doing two things-

1. Creating the big old JSON blob and then echoing it out to the github cli.
2. Using the github cli "api" command to actually send the payload, making it so I don't have to create any new tokens or mess around with authentication.

The actual GH command-

```
gh api repos/ORGANIZATION/REPO/hooks --input - -X POST
```

Since I've got `--input -` there it's reading my payload from stdin. You could also put the payload in a file and use that as the argument. I'm also explicitly setting it to "POST". You can use this method with any of the Github API (including graphql).